# Capturing Street Address Through Voice for Bixby

Tags: bixby

I am writing a Bixby capsule and one of the inputs is street address.

One method that I have tried is creating the following structure:

```
structure (FullAddress) {
  description (Address of a house)
  property (addressNumber) {
    type (geo.StreetNumber)
    min (Required)
    description (Address Number)
  }
  property (addressStreet) {
    type (geo.StreetName)
    min (Required)
    description (Street Name)
  }
  property (addressSuffix) {
    type (geo.StreetSuffix)
    min (Required)
    description (Street Name)
  }
}
```

with a constructor action to put the 3 inputs together.

I have seen that given an address `19 Fake Fields Street` the `geo.StreetName` typed input sometimes is able to understand `Fake Fields` and sometimes just `Fake` and drops `Fields`.

Also Bixby's speech to text sometimes hears `app` or `have` instead of `ave` for the `geo.StreetSuffix` value which makes it prompt the user for a suffix.

Is there a way to get Bixby to understand a street address with a little more accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Basically you need more training examples, which include 2 or 3 words as street names. Try to have at least 3 examples with **xxx fakexxx fields street**, and test in simulator the utterance **yyy fakeyyy fields street** to see if Bixby can capture **fields** as part of the address name. The goal here is to train Bixby to learn that there might be 2 or even 3 words ahead of **addressSuffix**. After that you can try utterance **zzz fakezzz creek street** without ever using **creek** in the training to confirm Bixby not just learned **fields**. Please read more in [this article](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011473333).
2. There is no easy way when come to speech recognition. You can include a [vocab model](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/training.vocabulary) to force "app" to be "ave", but what if user truly want say the word **app** or **have**? I would think the user can type ave or blvd, but need to say the word **avenue** instead of ave, and **boulevard** instead of blvd.

Comment: This is a good answer, thank you! When a user is speaking, they will say ave instead of avenue, expecting otherwise is guaranteeing a bad user experience. Unfortunately, right now when someone says `ave` Bixby's speech to text cannot tell the difference from `app` or `have` so even if a user meant to say one of those words, when I am expecting an address, I need to assume they meant `ave` because the other 2 words wouldnt make as much sense contextually. I created a vocab file to fix this and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use the viv.geo.SearchTerm in training and viv.geo.NamedPoint in your action. This let a user say something incomplete like "1 Market Street, California" and Bixby will use a HERE maps search to find this in San Francisco.

To use, setup a NamedPoint concept (after importing viv.geo)

```
structure (InputAddress) {
  role-of (geo.NamedPoint)
}
```

Then in your action, you can do something like:

```
    input (namedPoint) {
      type (InputAddress)
      min (Required) max (One)
      default-select {
        with-learning
        with-rule {
          select-first
        }
      }
    }
```

In this example, using learning and select-first will automatically select the first address. Without this, Bixby will autosuggest addresses.

namedPoint will then be passed to your endpoint and you can parse as needed.

In training, use geo.SearchTerm - for example:

`[g:GetAddressAction] My address is {[g:InputAddress] (665 Clyde Ave Mountain View California)[v:geo.SearchTerm]}`

or for a prompt, you could use:

`[g:GetAddressAction:continue:InputAddress] {[g:InputAddress] (60 S Market)[v:geo.SearchTerm]}`

You can get a more fully formatted address by letting Bixby handle it by using the viv.geo.ResolveAddressByPlaceID goal. Here is a complete action using NamedPoint and ResolveAddressByPlaceID. Note the links to the relevant docs in comments

```
action (GetAddressAction) {
  type(Search)
  description (Get Address)
  collect {
    // See https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library.geo#using-searchterm - used in training
    // and https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library.geo#namedpoint - used below and for computed-input
    input (namedPoint) {
      type (InputAddress)
      min (Required) max (One)
      default-select {
        with-learning
        with-rule {
          select-first
        }
      }
      // hidden - Hide if all you need is address
    }
    computed-input (address){
      type (geo.Address)
      min (Optional) max (One)
      compute {
        intent {
          goal: viv.geo.ResolveAddressByPlaceID
          value: $expr(namedPoint.placeID)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  output (geo.Address)
}
```